# Qt 2 or 3d bool list access from qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm a begginer in QT, I'm trying to pass a 2d bool QList as a Q_PROPERTY into QML, but unfortunately it fails. When I trying to simple (1d) QList and  qml rootItem.chkbool[0] is correct (it works), but 2d QList is fail:

main.cpp

```
 Object myObj;
        QQmlContext* ctx = engine->rootContext();
        ctx->setContextProperty("rootItem", (QObject *)&myObj);
```

qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.5
import QtQml.Models 2.2

Window {
    flags:  Qt.ToolTip | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground
    color: "#00000000"
    visible: true
    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CheckBox {
            id:chk
            checked: rootItem.chkbool[0][0]
        }

}
```

object_.h

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H
#define RECEIVER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QList>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( QList<QList<bool>> chkbool READ getBoolChange NOTIFY changeOfStatus )

 public:
  Object() {
      enbeddedList.push_back(true);
      enbeddedList.push_back(false);
      list.append(enbeddedList);

      emit changeOfStatus();
  }

  QList<QList<bool>> getBoolChange(){
      return list;
  }

  signals:
   void changeOfStatus();

  private:
   QList<bool> enbeddedList;
   QList<QList<bool>> list;
   bool changeMe;
   int theValue;
   QTimer *myTimer;

};
#endif // RECEIVER_H
```

Anyone know a correct code for that?

Comment: According to [Data Type Conversion](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html) document you should provide `QVariantList` or `QVariantMap` to pass arrays from C++ to QML/JS. But if you have some complicated data it's much better to use setter/getter of your custom object to pass a data. `rootItem.get(0,0)` instead of `rootItem.chkbool[0][0]`

Comment: Have you tried registering the list? i.e. call `qRegisterMetatype<QList<QList<bool>>>();`

Answer (score 0):

Data Type Conversion was right (from [folibis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2981610/folibis)).

Here is the correct code:

object_.h

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H
#define RECEIVER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QList>
#include <QMetaType>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( QVariantList chkbool READ getBoolChange NOTIFY changeOfStatus )

 public:
  Object() {

      QVariantList variant;
      variant.append(true);
      variant.append(false);
      list.insert(list.size() ,variant);

      emit changeOfStatus();
  }

  QVariantList getBoolChange(){
      return list;
  }

  signals:
   void changeOfStatus();

  private:
   QVariantList list;
   bool changeMe;
   int theValue;
   QTimer *myTimer;

};
#endif // RECEIVER_H
```

Thanks for All!